# cmd start with multiple arguments

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, wsl2

In WSL2, I often like to open a set of files (typically PDFs) all at once.

Using this bash script, until recently it's been working:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Copyright (C) 2014, Alexey Pavlov
#   mailto:alexpux@gmail.com
# This file is part of Minimal SYStem version 2.
#   https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/
# File: start

COMSPEC="/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe"

declare -a ARG
for arg in "${@}" ; do
    arg=$(wslpath -wa "${arg}")
    ARG=("${ARG[@]}" "${arg//&/^&}")
done
echo "${ARG[@]}"

"$COMSPEC" /c start '' "${ARG[@]}"
```

(I saved this as `~/bin/oo`, since I like quick 2-letter commands.)

Usage:

```bash
$ oo *.pdf
c:\full\path\A1.pdf c:\full\path\A2.pdf c:\full\path\B1.pdf c:\full\path\B2.pdf
```

(The echoed filenames are there mostly for debugging, other than that the script does not need to echo anything to the screen.)

Until recently, this would use my system PDF-reader (sumatra pdf, but that seems to not matter much) and open *all* of the files all at once. However, after some recent "update", it only opens the first of the files.

This does the same with a collection of PNGs too, it is not unique to file type or the pdf-reader application.

My workaround for now is to do

```bash
$ oo .
```

which opens a windows explorer in the current directory, and then select all of the relevant files and hit `Enter`, which then starts my pdf-reader with all files open.

Is this change something over which I have control? (Is there a better way to do this?)

Comment: I don't know your problem but given the change that happened.. you might want to work `"$COMSPEC" /c start '' "${ARG[@]}"` into your for loop?  This should circumvent the change assuming that single instance vs multiple instance is not your problem.

Comment: I find it strange that your code ever worked : the `start` command only accepts one command, and the rest of the line are the arguments for the command. The suggestion by @SeñorCMasMas should work.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I had thought of that, and due to a finite turnaround-time I was trying to avoid the visual artifacts of doing that ... yes, that may be the best way to do what I aim to, and just accept it.

Comment: @harrymc I had wondered about that. Perhaps it worked as a "bug" and they just "fixed the glitch". Bummer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` really only launches **one** file at a time, with the rest being included as command-line arguments to the launch of that file. So if you try to `start` multiple files at once, they will all be passed to the same program – the one that the *first* file is associated to.

When the default shell verb is being looked up from the Registry, a `%1` in the command is expanded to the file name while `%2`, `%3` &c. are the additional arguments. For example, `.mdb` (Access.MDBFile) has the following under `shell\open\command`:

```
> reg query HKCR\.mdb
Access.MDBFile

> reg query HKCR\Access.MDBFile\shell\open\command
"C:\Program Files\[..]\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" /NOSTARTUP "%1" %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

This means that starting `foo.mdb /wrkgrp shared.mdw` (as if foo.mdb were a program) will result in the extra parameters `/wrkgrp` `shared.mdw` being passed to MSACCESS.EXE through `%2` `%3`.

When you try to `start` multiple files this way, the program will receive their names all at once (though the rest will likely be unquoted and you'll have problems with spaces in filenames – and they cannot be quoted due to being optional) and will hopefully open all of them at once.

On the other hand, PuTTY's `.ppk` (PPK_Assoc_ProgId) has the `open` verb defined as:

```
> assoc .ppk
.ppk=PPK_Assoc_ProgId

> ftype PPK_Assoc_ProgId
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pageant.exe" "%1"
```

In this case, because the command only includes `"%1"`, any additional options *will not* be passed to pageant.exe – only the file name will be.

To be sure, I've tested this on Windows XP SP3 with Process Monitor running to see the command line being passed to the new process. If I run `start a.txt b.txt c.txt` (with the standard Windows association of .txt with Notepad only having `%1`), only *one* of those files is listed in the command line of the Notepad.exe process.

So it really *does* depend on the specific program and the way it has set up its file associations – and in situations where it happens to work, it works more by accident than by intention. Use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't think that it might be a change with SumatraPDF (since that's the vast-majority of my use-case here). Confusingly, I have SumatraPDF set to be the primary handler of PDF files (and it works), but `assoc` returns `.pdf=Acrobat.Document.DC` and `ftype` reflects the use of `acrobat.exe`, so while I don't understand while assoc/ftype are incorrect, your answer suggests where else I can look. Thanks! (Looking some more ...)

Comment: Win8+ has a different way "default" applications are set, I think, so `assoc` is not as useful. But even if it doesn't show up directly under HKCR\.pdf, you can still track down the individual classes like Acrobat.Document.DC or Sumatra.Something.OrOther under HKCR and still look at their shell verbs (shell\open\command).